# Parse Strings to type in generic

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T, P>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, P> predicate, String filter) { 

  String[] values = _service.GetValues(filter);

}
```

The variable values is something like:

```
String[] values = { "1", "2", "C" };
```

I need to parse all values to the same type of P. So if P is of type `int` then it would fail because I would not be able to parse C to int. But if P would be of type String then it would pass since all 3 values can be parsed to String.

The types of P would be the basic ones: int, datetime, float, double, string, boolean ...

How to do this?

Comment: How to do _what_, **exactly**? Can you give an example of what you want to do without generics? How can you "parse" a string to a type (where I assume you mean an instance of a type)?

Comment: Pretty sure he wants "value1, value2, value3" parsed in to 3 instances of whatever type `P` is.  Not sure this is possible unless `P` is filtered to a class that supports some kind of `Parse` method.

Comment: You're not even using half of your parameters.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just update my question. Does it help?

Comment: @MiguelMoura You just sort of fizzled out. What my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new method to do the conversion for you.

```
public IEnumerable<P> Parse<P>(string[] values) where P : IConvertable // Add constraint for some compile time notification errors
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        yield return (P)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(P));
    }
}
```

Another option if you didn't want a new method would be to use this line.

```
var convertedValues = values.Select(value => (P)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(P)));
```

On the one line option if you add a `.ToList()` to the end it will do all the conversions at the line of assignment so it will cause the exception to be thrown immediately.

```
var convertedValues = values.Select(value => (P)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(P))).ToList();
```

Comment: What happens if it not convertible? Can I catch the exception for that one?

Comment: With the `yield` the Convert doesn't happen until that value is used. When it is used if it cannot convert it would throw a `System.FormatException`

Comment: Sorry, SO went funny, did not mean the comment and the downvote, both reverted :D

Comment: I can't get an exception when the value is used. I need to know if all values are convertible to P type and if they are then use it. If at least one is not then I do something else ...

Comment: @MattRowland Can I check first if all are convertible without throwing the exception?

Comment: To do it without the exception you would need to use each specific type's `TryParse`. This could be a very large switch/if statement.

Comment: Why wouldn't you type-constrain the `P` to `IConvertible`? Wouldn't that give you compile-time checks?

Comment: @KennethK It would give some compile time checks. For `int` and `string` they already implement it so it doesn't matter in this case. Good call though, I will add it to the answer.